# how to select values inside bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion that has a form inside. When a button inside each accordion is clicked, it retrieves `title` and `query` contents of the same accordion.

https://jsfiddle.net/rkdrfj4y/3/ this is a demonstration of what I am attempting to do.

The problem is that the first accordion always returns undefined `form` `input` value. All the other subsequent accordions return the expected values. I don't understand how this can happen because identical js code is used for each accordion.

HTML

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Global Templates</label>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-global">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="title-anchor" data-toggle="collapse"
                               data-parent="#accordion-global" href="#collapse-global-0">
                                title</a>
                        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-global-0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="query-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="template-title">Template Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control template-title" name="template-title" value="title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="template-query">Template Query</label>
                <textarea class="form-control template-query" name="template-query" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)">query</textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
            <input class="query-id" type="hidden" value="_id">
            <button class="btn btn-info apply-template-btn">Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="title-anchor" data-toggle="collapse"
                               data-parent="#accordion-global" href="#collapse-global-1">
                                title</a>
                        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-global-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="query-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="template-title">Template Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control template-title" name="template-title" value="title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="template-query">Template Query</label>
                <textarea class="form-control template-query" name="template-query" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)">query</textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
            <input class="query-id" type="hidden" value="_id">
            <button class="btn btn-info apply-template-btn">Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.apply-template-btn').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

let id = $(this).siblings('.query-id').val();
let title = $(this).siblings('.query-form').find('.template-title').val();
let query = $(this).siblings('.query-form').find('.template-query').val();

console.log([id,title,query])
alert(title)    //undefined for first accordion but works for all other subsequent accordions

$.post('/api/database/query_template/update', {id,title,query}, function (data) {
    console.log(data)   
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below existing lines:

```
let title = $(this).siblings('.query-form').find('.template-title').val();
let query = $(this).siblings('.query-form').find('.template-query').val();
```

to

```
let title = $(this).parent().find(".template-title").val();
let query = $(this).parent().find(".template-query").val();
```

Comment: thanks for that. But why does the bottom work and the top one doesn't work for the first accordion?

Comment: If you type `$(this).siblings()` in browser console, you don't see a form with `.query-form` as a sibling. I am not sure whether form tags are considered when we call `siblings()`.  Instead of `parent()` you can also call `let title = $(this).siblings("div.form-group").find(".template-title").val()' which will give you the same result.